# How can I add one to a field in my database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a database whit 2 columns (name(text) and asist(int)) I want to add one to the asist field but I don't think I'm doing in the right way, so far I have this code.

```
public void update(String []names,int howany){

    for(int i=0;i<howmany;i++){
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("asist", +1);
    this.getWritableDatabase().update("Names", valores, "name="+names[i],null);
    }

}
```

thanks for the help! : )

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
valores.put("asist", "asist + 1");
this.getWritableDatabase().update("Names", valores, "name="+names[i],null);
```

Comment: This will set the value in the `asist` column to the string `'asist + 1'`.

Answer (score 1):

The `update` method does not support SQL expressions for new values;
you would have to read the old value and increment it in your program.

A better way is to write the entire SQL statement directly:

```
getWritableDatabase().execSQL(
    "UPDATE Names SET asist = asist + 1 WHERE name = ?",
    new Object[]{ names[i] });
```

Comment: thanks! but one more questions well two more XD what is the meaning of the character "?" next to name? and the code for the Sql statement goes into my SQLiteOpenHelper subclass right? pd: sorry if i don't write correctly but i'm in the process to learn English

Comment: The `?` is a parameter marker, which allows you to use values without having to format and escape them (which becomes troublesome when the string contains quotes or special characters), and avoids security problems [like this](http://xkcd.com/327/).